# Method to check if ActionCable subscription for given channel already exists on js consumer side?

Tags: javascript, actioncable, consumer

I want to add consumer subscription when modal is opened because only in that case I need to receive some channel messages. I know I can list subscriptions with *consumer.subscriptions* and there's an array of identifiers returned, but is there any js method to check if given channel is already subscribed, sth. like *consumer.isSubscribed('FooChannel')* ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create the subscription, only when the modal is open and avoid the unnecessary check. Alternatively, you can utilize `subscriptions#findAll` to implement the `isSubscribed` method

```js
consumer.subscriptions.isSubscribed = function (channelID) {
  return this.findAll(channelID).length > 0
}
```

[findAll is defined here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actioncable/app/javascript/action_cable/subscriptions.js#L57)